# Is there a way to reduce/remove the redundant generic parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

Consider the following function:

```kotlin
abstract class ObservableCollection<E> : CoroutineScope, MutableCollection<E> {...}
class ObservableList<E>(override val backingSource: MutableList<E> = mutableListOf()) : ObservableCollection<E>(), MutableList<E> by backingSource {...}

inline fun <reified T : Event<E>, E> ObservableCollection<E>.on(scope: CoroutineScope = this, noinline consumer: suspend (T) -> Unit): Job =
    events.buffer(Channel.UNLIMITED)
        .filterIsInstance<T>().onEach {
            runCatching { consumer(it) }.onFailure { ObservableCollection.logger.catching(it) }
        }.catch { ObservableCollection.logger.catching(it) }
        .launchIn(scope)
```

To call it, the first and general way (which comes in mind):

```kotlin
val list = ObservableList<Int>()

list.on<ElementAddEvent<Int>, Int> {

}
```

To make it more idiomatic (towards removing redundancy of passing explicit generics), we can have something like this:

```kotlin
list.on { event: ElementAddEvent<Int> ->

}
```

But is there a way to remove that explicit generic type `<Int>` in `{ event: ElementAddEvent<Int> ->` as well? Since it is implicit, as coming from the type of ObservableList on which `on` method/function is called on.

#### Edit:

`Event<E>` is basically an interface to for all the possible events like `ElementRemoveEvent<E>`, `ElementAddEvent<E>`, `ElementReplaceEvent` etc.

```kotlin
interface Event<E> : CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = collection.coroutineContext

    val collection: ObservableCollection<E>
}

class ElementAddEvent<E>(
    val element: E,
    override val collection: ObservableCollection<E>
) : Event<E>

class ElementReplaceEvent<E>(
    val newElement: E,
    val oldElement: E,
    override val collection: ObservableCollection<E>
) : Event<E>

// And so-on...
```

It has basically nothing to do with the question, so I didn't put it on.

#### Edit 2:

One way could be to make static functions in each of the event like:

```kotlin
class ElementAddEvent<E>(
    val element: E,
    override val collection: ObservableCollection<E>
) : Event<E> {

    companion object {
        fun <E> on(collection: ObservableCollection<E>, consumer: suspend (ElementAddEvent<E>) -> Unit) {
            collection.on { event: ElementAddEvent<E> ->
                consumer(event)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This will make possible to be callable as:

```kotlin
ElementAddEvent.on(list) {

}
```

***But I think this will make too much noise in the sources***, so I would prefer to use the second approach posted in the question itself *(specifying type inside the lambda)*. If I missed something question is still open, you can let me know!

Comment: what is `events`, `Event`, `logger.catching`? Add minimal reproducible example

Comment: @IR42 logger.catching is simply to log the errors that were not catched by inside the flow, it comes from [this library](https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging). `events` is a getter without backing fields that gives `Flow` of `Event<E>` from a `BroadcastChannel`.

Comment: Actually there's no error involved here, I just wanted to know if there's a way to get rid of the `<Int>` or any generic type we have to write explicitly even if it is implicitly known from the type of `ObservableList<E>` it is called on.

Comment: there is no such feature in kotlin, you have to specify generic type argument explicitly

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure there is nothing like this in Kotlin. It would sort of be like the diamond operator in Java, which Kotlin doesn't have. Implicit parameters are all or nothing.